# Receiver (<DiamondDetail4.ScheduleService:) has no segue with identifier 'mySegue''

Tags: swift, segue

I have two view controllers - ScheduleService and CalendarDay. I created a manual segue from ScheduleService to CalendarDay by clicking and dragging from ScheduleService to CalendarDay. I was then very careful to set the name of the identifier to "mySegue". If I click the segue on the main storyboard, the storyboard segue shows the Identifier with the value "mySegue" in it (without the quotes of course).

Now in ScheduleService, I have the following function:

```
@IBAction func gotoCalendarDay() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }
```

I'm calling this function from a Swift file named "CalendarView.swift" like so:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let ss = ScheduleService()
        ss.gotoCalendarDay()
    }
```

The button that calls this function when pressed was programmatically created. So when I click the button I expected it to call the "gotoCalendarDay" function on the ScheduleService view controller. It apparently calls the function with no problem, but for some odd reason it's saying that the segue can't be found, even though I specifically gave the Identifier field in the Storyboard Segue panel a value.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

" let ss = ScheduleService() "， maybe this is the reason why your storyboard don't want to response your call; This "ss" is an object created by your "ScheduleService.swift" file without storyboard.

Init a viewController with storyboard should use some special methods, for example: 
" let ss = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScheduleServiceIdentifier") "
Hope this could help you :) .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually this did send me in a new direction. I added a bit onto the code you gave:

let ss = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScheduleService") as! ScheduleService

And now it does let me call ss.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)

The problem is the segue is never performed. But your answer definitely got me further than I was!

Comment: There is an usual way to check segue problems: Add breakpoint on" override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { print(segue.identifier) } " in controller"ScheduleService" , then run your project check the code behavior and console logs;  Before you do this, make sure you know how storyboard works,  your new problem is the same reason with old one.